# Show if value is same as Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`<%= user.last_seen_at.strftime("%I:%M UTC") %>` will give me a date of when the user last took an action on my website.

Doing `<%=Time.now.strftime("%I:%M UTC") %>` will give the current time.

I want it set up where it will show `<h1> online </h1>` if the value of <%= user.last_seen_at %> is the same or within 5min of `<%= Time.now.strftime("%I:%M UTC") %>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% = content_tag('h1','online') if (user.last_seen_at + 5.minutes) >= Time.current %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use Time.zone.now instead of Time.now

[Check this link](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to create a helper or instance method

```
def online?
  last_seen_at + 5.minutes >= Time.current
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the arbitrary interval of 5 mins is something you should **avoid hard-coding into the view**. It might be used across other views or practically anywhere in your app.

I'd recommend you write a helper as a centralized place where you store this 5 min tolerance and use it in your controller like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    helper TimeToleranceHelper
    ...
end
```

The helper itself should use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now` ([read more on this](http://winstonyw.com/2014/03/03/time_now_vs_time_zone_now/)).

It may look something like:

```
module TimeToleranceHelper
  TOLERANCE = 5.minutes

  def soon?(time)
    now = Time.zone.now

    (time..time + TOLERANCE).cover? now
  end
end
```